# Why is bitcoind so slow on VPSs?

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, performance

Sometimes it takes bitcoind more than a minute to respond to basic RPC calls such as getbalance (and on average, it takes at least 5 seconds), even though the "STAT" according to the Linux 'ps' program remains "`SLl`" (Sleeping!). I've confirmed I was looking at the RPC server process and not the client process. How is this even reasonable?

It shouldn't be possible to run large-scale sites like Mt. Gox with those kind of response times. What special considerations need to be taken into account to get performance out of bitcoind?

Comment: It takes slightly over 0.0s when I run it.  Is your bitcoind trying to sync with the blockchain while you run the RPC commands?
chris@chris:~$ time bitcoind getbalance
5.72535335

real 0m0.020s
user 0m0.000s
sys 0m0.016s
chris@chris:~$

Comment: Are you using an encrypted filesystem?  Are you using the most recent release?

Comment: @Chris Moore `bitcoind getblockcount` matches the block count returned by Block Explorer, so it's fully synced.

Comment: @StephenGornick I have v0.6.2-beta. However, the problem has persisted through multiple upgrades. I had the problem back when the current version was 0.3.4. Also, it's not an encrypted filesystem, but it is on an OpenVZ VPS.

Comment: If you are unable to resolve this you could try http://blockchain.info/json_rpc_api as an alternative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

bitcoind is often very slow when running over a remote disks (such as on a VPS), especially if that disk is slow.  Check the load of incoming transactions in debug.log, which lock cs_main during processing (which the RPC thread does as well).  If you have the memory, try tmpfs, or increase the bdb cache.

Comment: If it's a disk problem, the STAT should read "D" (uninterruptible sleep), shouldn't it? However, the filesystem type is `simfs`, so perhaps you're right.

Comment: It may not be the RPC thread that is stuck waiting on IO, if any thread holding cs_main (which is most of them when they do IO) is waiting on IO, the RPC thread will have to wait for the other(s) to finish their work.